# Simple PHP Simulation Script

Tags: php, simulation

I'm working on making a simple simulation for my website, and I've looked around but cannot find anything on how to accomplish this. Could someone please provide how I would achieve the following output with code:

---

There are two players, both level 2.

**Player 1**

Attack - 1
Defense - 2
Health - 10

**Player 1**

Attack - 2
Defense - 1
Health - 10

I want to to have a simulated turn-based battle between these two players. It would randomly choose who gets the first hit. For this we'll say player 1 goes first. 
The equation I would use to calculate the hit would be `($playerattack/$playerdefense) + rand(1,$level)` (equation may work well, may not. just for testing purposes) I want to then have output like the following.

Player 1 (10 health) - hit a 2

Player 2 (8 health) - hit a 1

. . .

Player 1 (1 health) - hit a 2

**Player 2 dies, Player 1 is victorious!**

**Sorry to those who answered to the old example! Thanks for your feedback though

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Do you have any code? What is your expected input and output? We need a *lot* more info.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is completely different from the example I gave, I just figured doing it like this would make it much simpler for other people to understand. I just have no clue how to go about any kind of simulation using php. Any example or finger to the right direction would be very helpful. I can make some sample code though.

Comment: "Simulation" is a very broad term, and PHP is just another programming language - there's very little difference in how you'd do any kind of calculations or simulation than in any other language. It sounds like you want to apply some sort of basic algorithm to some input data.

Comment: Yep, the example I gave is kind of confusing though. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This allows only two players.

```
$players = array(
  array('attack' => 1, 'defense' => 2, 'health' => 10, 'level' => 2, ), 
  array('attack' => 2, 'defense' => 1, 'health' => 10, 'level' => 2, ), 
);
$count = 0;
while (true) {
  $count++;
  $players_temp = $players;
  $attacker_key = array_rand($players);
  $attacker     =& $players[$attacker_key];
  unset($players_temp[$attacker_key]);
  $defender_key = array_rand($players_temp);
  $defender     =& $players[$defender_key];

  $hit = ($attacker['attack']/$defender['defense']) + rand(1, $attacker['level']);
  echo "{$count}. Player {$defender_key} ({$defender['health']} health) is hit a {$hit} by Player {$attacker_key} ({$attacker['health']} health)\n";
  $defender['health'] = $defender['health'] - $hit;

  if ($defender['health'] <= 0) {
    echo "Player {$defender_key} dies, Player {$attacker_key} is victorious!\n";
    break;
  }

}
```

[Edited]
This allows more than two players and is turn based.

```
set_time_limit(1);
$players = array(
  'A' => array('attack' => 1, 'defense' => 2, 'health' => 10, 'level' => 2, ), 
  'B' => array('attack' => 2, 'defense' => 1, 'health' => 10, 'level' => 2, ), 
  'C' => array('attack' => 1, 'defense' => 1, 'health' => 10, 'level' => 2, ), 
  'D' => array('attack' => 2, 'defense' => 2, 'health' => 10, 'level' => 2, ), 
);
$player_ids = array_keys($players);
$no_of_players = sizeof($player_ids);
$count = 0;
while (true) {
  $defender_key=0;
  for ($attacker_key=0;$attacker_key<$no_of_players;$attacker_key++) {
    if (!isset($player_ids[$attacker_key])) continue;
    $count++;
    $attacker_id  = $player_ids[$attacker_key];
    $attacker     =& $players[$attacker_id];

    $defender_key = $attacker_key + 1;
    while (!isset($player_ids[$defender_key])) {
      $defender_key = ($defender_key+1 < $no_of_players) ?  $defender_key + 1 : 0;
    }
    $defender_id  = $player_ids[$defender_key];
    $defender     =& $players[$defender_id];

    $hit = round(($attacker['attack']/$defender['defense']) + rand(1, $attacker['level']), 2);
    echo "{$count}. Player {$attacker_id} ({$attacker['health']} health) has hit a {$hit} on Player {$defender_id} ({$defender['health']} health)<br />";
    $defender['health'] = $defender['health'] - $hit;

    if ($defender['health'] <= 0) {
      echo "Player {$defender_id} dies<br />";
      unset($players[$defender_id], $player_ids[$defender_key]);
      if (sizeof($player_ids) == 1) {
        echo "Player {$attacker_id} is victorious!<br />";
        break 2;
      }
    }

    //if ($count > 100) break 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I just tested it out a couple times, and it works exactly how I wanted it to, except one small problem. Is there a way it goes turn based? So player one attacks, then player 2, and so on. This is the output I got.

`1. Player 1 (10 health) - hit a 2 
2. Player 0 (10 health) - hit a 3 
3. Player 0 (7 health) - hit a 2 
4. Player 1 (8 health) - hit a 2 
5. Player 1 (6 health) - hit a 2 
6. Player 1 (4 health) - hit a 3 
7. Player 0 (5 health) - hit a 2 
8. Player 0 (3 health) - hit a 2 
9. Player 0 (1 health) - hit a 2 
Player 0 dies, Player 1 is victorious!`

Comment: Sorry if my original example misled you. What I'm trying to achieve is a turn-based fight where player 1 gets a turn, then player 2, and they fight until one of them dies.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an array or a-j.
Run a loop 5 times (for loop) that picks a random value then removes the value from the array.

```
$arr = array('a', 'b',..., 'j');

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $key = array_rand($arr);
    echo $arr[$key], "<br />";
    unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

Comment: I think just `shuffle()`ing the array and outputting it will be enough

Comment: I think the OP's original question said there were cards a-j, not only a-e. So you'd need to shuffle and `array_slice()` I guess

Answer (score 0):

This PHP code:

```
$arr = array('A','B','C','D','E');
shuffle($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo ($i + 1) . '. ' . $arr[$i] . "<br/>";
}
```

Will output something similar to:

> 1. E
> 2. C
> 3. A
> 4. D
> 5. B

**Edit:**

To accomplish your second example you would use something along the lines of:

```
while ($player1->health > 0 && $player2->health > 0) {
    ...
    echo "Player X (health X)....";
}
if ($player1->health == 0) echo "Player 1 died!";
else echo "Player 2 died!";
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the example to try and make it more clear. Thanks for your feedback though! Could this still be used in the same way?

Comment: I edited my answer for your second example.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know I would do the code for the actual simulation, though? Like for when they're "fighting"?